# Drill Across - Oracle BAM 12c

Tags: oracle12c, oracle-bam

Does anybody know how to use Drill Across? I have a Business View from the type Pie and I want to go to another dashboard when I click on some slice. I have configured all the fields on Drill Across tab but when I click on the graph slice nothing happens.